# sql - the data equals to the end of the months within the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date-range

i need the data which equals to the end of the months in the same table.

what i was struggling so far is :

```
SELECT * FROM LG_006_01_EMFLINE H 

 where h.DATE_ in (


declare @start datetime
declare @end datetime

select @Start = (select MIN(mm.date_) as minimum FROM LG_006_01_EMFLINE mm where mm.accountcode like '335%' and mm.DATE_ > '2016-04-01')
select @End =  (select MAX(nn.date_) FROM LG_006_01_EMFLINE nn where nn.accountcode like '335%' and nn.DATE_ > '2016-04-01')
;With CTE as
(
Select @Start  as Date,Case When DatePart(mm,@Start)<>DatePart(mm,@Start+1) then 1 else 0 end as [Last]
UNION ALL
Select Date+1,Case When DatePart(mm,Date+1)<>DatePart(mm,Date+2) then 1 else 0 end from CTE
Where Date<@End
)

Select date  from CTE
where [Last]=1   OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 ) )
```

the error i get is :

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'declare'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 26 Incorrect syntax near
>   ')'.

thanks in advance...

Comment: What flavour of SQL? mySQL, SQL Server, etc? Also, why are your `declare` statements inside a select?

Comment: You can't have a `declare` inside of a sub-select. And the `;` goes at the **end** of a statement. Not in the middle of a sub-select

Comment: @JohnHC SQL  Server 2008

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that is why i am here to ask for help, i dont have much idea ... need your suggestions...

Comment: the code within the parenthesis works just fine... (starts with " in ( "  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the code within your `in` statement works fine on its own, but as a_horse_with_no_name correctly pointed out, you can't have `declare` statements or `cte`s within a sub select.

Consequently you need to rearrange your query a little.  As you have not provided your source schema or data I have not been able to test this:

```
declare @start datetime
declare @end datetime

select @Start = (select MIN(mm.date_) as minimum
                 FROM LG_006_01_EMFLINE mm
                 where mm.accountcode like '335%'
                   and mm.DATE_ > '20160401'    -- Remove the hyphens to ensure SQL knows exactly what your date is, avoiding localisation issues.
                )

select @End =  (select MAX(nn.date_)
                from LG_006_01_EMFLINE nn
                where nn.accountcode like '335%'
                   and nn.DATE_ > '20160401'    -- Remove the hyphens to ensure SQL knows exactly what your date is, avoiding localisation issues.
                )

;With CTE as
(
Select @Start as Date
      ,Case When DatePart(mm,@Start) <> DatePart(mm,@Start+1) then 1 else 0 end as [Last]

union all

Select Date+1
      ,Case When DatePart(mm,Date+1) <> DatePart(mm,Date+2) then 1 else 0 end
from CTE
Where Date < @End
)
select *
from LG_006_01_EMFLINE H 
where h.DATE_ in (
                 Select date
                 from CTE
                 where [Last]=1
                 )
option ( maxrecursion 0 )
```

Comment: thanks a lot, works like a charm ! 

 i simply had no idea how to re-arrange the code!